# QGIS. get intersect line segments from polygons

Tags: qgis, vector, qgis-2.18

I have 2 types of Polygons. one big Polygon (P1) and multiple smaller polygons (P2) all located inside P1.

Is there a way to get the line segments that intersect/touch?.

Running "Geoprocessing Intersect" gives me the polygons. I only need the actual lines segments that touch not the whole polygons.

I'm attaching an example image, I need to get the red line. Is it possible to do this automatically?  [image: Get Intersecting line from polygons]

Answer (score 2):

In the GRASS toolbox, you can use :

```
grass.run_command('v.overlay', ainput=yourlines, atype='line',
                           binput=polygon2, output=result,
                           operator='and', snap='2')
```

You can adjust snap value if your lines not exactly overlap the polygon limits.